# Porting from Qt 4.x to Qt 5

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qt4.8

Has anybody ported a Qt 4.x application to Qt 5? We are about to port some software that makes extensive use of Qt 4.8. We use the Core, GUI, Network, OpenGL, Test, Webkit, and Xml libraries and our software is available on Windows, OS X, and Linux.

If you have experience in porting Qt 4.x applications to Qt 5, did you encounter any specific problems?

Comment: Have you tried to build it in Qt5? All I had to do with my apps was updating the project file, rebuild, and insert some #ifdefs here and there for renamed/moved identifiers so that it builds both in Qt4 and Qt5.

Comment: Webkit have some problems under some 64 bits platforms (namely Windows), being not provided. Qt 5.0.1 has been recently released, but I don't know if those issues have been corrected. Despite this, everything worked very so far for me.

Comment: Sounds good. We have not started the process of porting to Qt 5 yet but will most likely do so in the next few weeks. Reason I asked was because porting from Qt 3 to Qt 4 was a huge effort with a lot of code rewriting due to many deprecated classes and we would like to be better prepared this time. I will look into the Webkit 64bit issue on Windows. Thanks for the information!

Comment: The Qt community has taken some measures to reduce the changes necessary to upgrade from Qt4 to Qt5. They were specially concerned about not turning it as difficulty as it were with Qt3 to Qt4, as you have mentioned. You are welcome!

Comment: We ported all our software from Qt 4.8 to Qt 5.3 some time ago and it went very well. Very few changes to the code was necessary to get everything work properly. The port is a breeze compared to the Qt 3 to Qt 4 port.